# Find all occurrences of object instantiation

Tags: c#, optimization, resharper, instantiation

I'm developing a C# Mono project (in Unity3D) which is using an older version of the garbage collector. Memory leaks have been an unpleasant wake-up call for me.

Because of this I am optimizing as much as I possibly can: avoiding Linq like the plague, recycling collections, etc.

What I would like to know is - is there a tool that will let me know all of the places I am instantiating new objects?

I've been able to grep for things like `new List` which is fine, but if I want to expand my search to `new` I also get value types, which I want to ignore.

I'm using MonoDevelop, Visual Studio 2013 and Resharper.

Comment: Resharper will tell you where a constructor is used.

Comment: How can I find this functionality?

Comment: Have you tried [Heapshot](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/debug+profile/profile/heapshot/)?

Comment: Put the cursor on the constructor or a use of the constructor and **Reshaper\Find\Find Usages** menu item;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a relatively new little plug-in that JetBrains released for ReSharper that statically analyses your code for allocations and boxing - the [ReSharper Heap Allocations Viewer](https://github.com/controlflow/resharper-heapview). It might be exactly what you're looking for. We've had issues with garbage collection, memory usage and performance linked to excessive allocation and over-use of LINQ in performance-critical areas. It can be difficult to track these extra allocations down, as you've found too. This plugin has really helped when we've been refactoring to reduce allocations, and we've kept it on to prevent excessive memory use in new code.

Basically, it adds underlining and an explanation wherever it detects local object allocation, e.g.:

[image]

It also flags up LINQ statements, the allocations of iterators and delegates, and allocations caused by delegates.

You can install it from the ReSharper Extension Manager - just search for "heap allocations viewer".

Comment: This is looking excellent. Is there any way to output all of the instances of object allocations? For example, in a format like the code issue explorer.

Comment: You should be able to alt+enter on an allocation and show all similar code issues.

Comment: I gave that a go, it didn't seem to work for me. I don't know of a way to output all of the instances of object allocations. Perhaps that would make a good feature request? We used the plug-in after profiling, so we knew approximately where our excessive allocations were occurring.

Comment: I've been using the module and scanning through each script by eye. It's a bit of a pin, but it's taught me some very interesting things. For example, I had NO idea that calling params[] methods instantiated a new array every time.

Answer (score 0):

**[2021 Update]**

It looks like the Resharper heap allocation viewer extension has been merged into Resharper *Usages of Symbol* generic tool.

If you are using Resharper in 2021 and look for instantiation of a class, do the following steps :

- Go to the class definition and query *Usages of Symbol*, cf. screenshot below
- Click *Show in Find Results* for better readability
- Filter results by *New instance creation*

That's it, all your instantiations are now listed.

[image]